# Error in a minimal tkSimpleDialog example

Tags: python, tkinter

I was trying out a python code example at [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/User_input/Graphical#Python) - a [programming chrestomathy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrestomathy) site, where solutions to the same task are presented in as many different programming languages as possible. For this task, the goal is to input a string and the integer 75000, from graphical user interface. The code is shown below:

```
import tkSimpleDialog

number = tkSimpleDialog.askinteger("Integer", "Enter a Number")
string = tkSimpleDialog.askstring("String", "Enter a String")
```

However, when I try to run the code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vix\Documents\.cache\GUIexample.py", line 3, in <module>
    number = tkSimpleDialog.askinteger("Integer", "Enter a Number")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\tkSimpleDialog.py", line 262, in askinteger
    d = _QueryInteger(title, prompt, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\tkSimpleDialog.py", line 189, in __init__
    Dialog.__init__(self, parent, title)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\tkSimpleDialog.py", line 53, in __init__
    if parent.winfo_viewable():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'winfo_viewable'
```

Where could the problem be?

Thanks

Comment: Post the full traceback, not just the error. We need to see the code the error is in.

Comment: @agf I've edited the question to include the traceback.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7 on Windows 7 Ultimate 32-Bit. `root = Tkinter.tk()` does not work, it gives `NameError: name 'Tkinter' is not defined`

Comment: @agf Thanks for the heads up, creating a root window is what is required here. Your suggestion: `import Tkinter` and then `root = Tkinter.Tk()` works, However, you need to add `root.withdraw()` to complete the solution. You can post the answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The error message is telling you that the dialog needs a parent window.

With Python 2.x, you create the root window with:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import simpledialog
root = tkinter.Tk()
```

To hide the root window if you don't want it, use:

```
root.withdraw()
```

See the [Python Tkinter Docs](http://docs.python.org/library/tkinter.html) for more info.

Comment: *T*k instead of tk... Right answer by the way.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used `askinteger`, but judging from the error message it looks like the dialog needs to know its parent but you're not telling it what its parent should be. Try adding `parent=widget` (where "widget" is a reference to some other widget -- typically the root widget). I can't find any documentation that says this is required, but I'm guessing it is since all Tkinter widgets except the root window need to have a parent.

If the code you show in your question is the complete code, you're missing some other things. You need to create an instance of the `Tk` class (called the "root" window), and you need to start the event loop (though, it's possible that the dialog runs it's own event loop, so you might be OK if all you need is the single dialog).