# A popout window that receives an value from the user

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create a simple tkinter function, that i can use to receive a value from the user (like raw_input, but with a popout window).
for example, if the function is "getFromUser()", I will be able to use it like this:

```
value=getFromUser()
```

and then to do something else with what I recived.

Comment: Ok, so you want to create a popup window. What part of the problem do you need help with? Have you searched this site or the internet for solutions and not been able to make them work? If so, show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the tkinter.tksimpledialog package:
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-entry-dialogs.htm

Comment: I looked it up before I asked the question, and gave it up after it didn't work. i had the same problem as the problem in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205295/error-in-a-minimal-tksimpledialog-example , but the solutions didn't help.

Comment: I am sorry, i just found my mistake. Very stupid one, I didn't create a parent window, sorry, and thanks.